# Caffe Import error: libopencv_highgui.so.3.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: caffe, importerror

I created a virtual environment for python2.7 and I installed caffe using the command **conda install -c conda-forge caffe**. But when I try to import caffe, its throwing the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/data/home/eex608/.conda/envs/MyPython2.7Caffe/lib/python2.7/site-packages/caffe/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .pycaffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, RMSPropSolver, AdaDeltaSolver, AdamSolver, NCCL, Timer
File "/data/home/eex608/.conda/envs/MyPython2.7Caffe/lib/python2.7/site-packages/caffe/pycaffe.py", line 13, in <module>
from ._caffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, \
ImportError: libopencv_highgui.so.3.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this error?

The package info after I installed caffe (if this info is useful to debug)

```
2018-10-08 23:07:03  (rev 1)
 anaconda  {5.3.0 -> custom}
 blas  {1.0 -> 1.1 (conda-forge)}
 ca-certificates  {2018.03.07 -> 2018.8.24 (conda-forge)}
 certifi  {2018.8.24 -> 2018.8.24 (conda-forge)}
 h5py  {2.8.0 -> 2.8.0 (conda-forge)}
 harfbuzz  {1.8.8 -> 1.7.6}
 hdf5  {1.10.2 -> 1.10.1 (conda-forge)}
 matplotlib  {2.2.3 -> 2.2.3 (conda-forge)}
 mkl-service  {1.1.2 -> 1.1.2}
 mkl_fft  {1.0.4 -> 1.0.6 (conda-forge)}
 mkl_random  {1.0.1 -> 1.0.1 (conda-forge)}
 numexpr  {2.6.8 -> 2.6.6 (conda-forge)}
 numpy  {1.15.1 -> 1.15.2 (conda-forge)}
 numpy-base  {1.15.1 -> 1.15.2}
 openssl  {1.0.2p -> 1.0.2p (conda-forge)}
 pyqt  {5.9.2 -> 5.6.0}
 pytables  {3.4.4 -> 3.4.4 (conda-forge)}
 qt  {5.9.6 -> 5.6.3}
 qtconsole  {4.4.1 -> 4.4.1 (conda-forge)}
 scikit-learn  {0.19.2 -> 0.20.0 (conda-forge)}
 scipy  {1.1.0 -> 1.1.0 (conda-forge)}
+boost-1.66.0 (conda-forge)
+boost-cpp-1.66.0 (conda-forge)
+caffe-1.0 (conda-forge)
+ffmpeg-3.2.4 (conda-forge)
+gflags-2.2.1 (conda-forge)
+giflib-5.1.4 (conda-forge)
+glog-0.3.5 (conda-forge)
+jasper-1.900.1 (conda-forge)
+leveldb-1.18 (conda-forge)
+libgcc-7.2.0 (conda-forge)
+libgfortran-3.0.0 (conda-forge)
+libiconv-1.15 (conda-forge)
+libopenblas-0.3.3
+libprotobuf-3.5.2 (conda-forge)
+libwebp-0.5.2 (conda-forge)
+lmdb-0.9.22 (conda-forge)
+openblas-0.2.20 (conda-forge)
+opencv-3.4.1 (conda-forge)
+protobuf-3.5.2 (conda-forge)
+python-gflags-3.1.2 (conda-forge)
+python-leveldb-0.193 (conda-forge)
+x264-1!152.20180717 (conda-forge)
```

Comment: Looks like even though conda installs opencv version of 3.4 as part of caffe installation, at the time of import, caffe expects opencv version of 3.3. You could actually find libopencv_highgui.so.3.4 at the path <path_to_conda>/envs/env_name/lib. Hence it looks more like a bug. Why don't you try caffe installation from a different channel?

Comment: same error. other caffe installtions from anaconda doesnt work too

Comment: @Khan Did you face issue with `conda install -c defaults caffe` and `conda install -c intel caffe`. Both works fine for me.

Comment: @AnjuPaul-Intel that worked for me, thanks

Comment: In my scenario, it looks like the current conda-forge version of opencv does not install libopencv_*.so files in env_name/lib. Probably a recent bug, since I have an older installation without this problem.